# Render Material from Desktop Duplication API

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, dxgi

I am fairly new to UE4 and C++ but have been a web developer for about 10 years. /lifestory

I am attempting to render a material (I think; not sure of the terminology) that can be applied to a plane/cube/flat surface that will act as a duplication of my desktop. I have worked through the [Desktop Duplication Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft but am just not sure how to port that code to work in UE4 as a material.

To be clear, this is not a "write this code for me" question.  I am simply looking for guidance.  Should I be looking into Render Targets?  Dynamic Materials/Textures?  I have no idea.

Any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sir, it's all about "Dynamic Materials/Textures" you can set your raw image data into UTexture2D
[this one may help =)](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Asynchronous_Image_Loading_from_Disk)